# Displaying data from JavaScript to HTML, load and disappear after 1 second, when I try to filter them with an if statement. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I'm new to JS and I have some issues with my items being displayed dynamically in the same HTML page. I have 3 categories of products. All of them have an ID of 1 (cheese) ,2(drinks) or 3(veggies).

Where do I need help and what I have tried: When I add the addEventListener, the product category that I want to be displayed is displayed for 0.5 second. When I remove it, it works. And I don't know why.  I have tried many possible ways to solve it but apparently I am stuck.

**NOTE: If I remove the event listener and the if else statement completely, the whole list of products is displayed perfectly. I will also post a picture of my products.**

Moreover, if I have 3 different caterogries and I also want to have one page of all the products, what is the most efficient way to do it? Having 3 if else statements and event listeners for the 3 different IDS otherwise display everything?

**I tried to explain in the comments to make your life easier. Btw the html is not needed to be posted as it works when I try to display all the products together**

```
  //just a button in navigation that will display the elements in my page dynamically
  //it will be used for the event clicker
  const cheeseHolder = document.querySelector('.cheeseProd');

  //the div that they will be displayed. .innerHtml will be used and .insertAdjacentHTML after that.
  const containerProducts = document.querySelector(".product-center-container");
  const displayProducts = function (products) {
    containerProducts.innerHTML = "";
  
    //there are 15 products for learning purposes in my products array. Every one of them is not an object but its displayed like that:
    //There are more products with different ids: 1,2,3
    // const cheeseItem1 = { p_image: "images/3cheese1.png", p_title: "Cheese1", p_price: 133, id:'3'};
    // products = [cheeseItem1]
    products.forEach((element) => {
      const html =`
      <div class="product-center-container">
      <div class="product">   
      <a href="pDescription.html"><img class ="p_image" src="${element.p_image}"></a>
      <h1 class="p_title">${element.p_title}</h1>
      <h4 class="p_price">${element.p_price}.-</h4>
      <button class="itemsToCart"><img src="images/cartAdd.png" alt="Basket displayed here"></button>
      </div>
      </div>
      `;
      
      //not sure about putting it here
      //have also tried displayProducts() with an eventListener outside of this function but it doesn't work
      cheeseHolder.addEventListener('click', function(){
        //if I remove the event listener anc I leave the statement below the category is displayed. 
        //When I add it it's displayed for 0.5 seconds.
        if (element.id === '3') {
          containerProducts.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html);
        }
      });
    });
  };
displayProducts(products);
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. Have you tried moving the condition outside the event listener? So `if(condition){cheeseholder.addeventlistener(...)}`. Right now you're adding an event listener for each item.

Comment: @Even if I move it outside the event listenter I should still have it all in the loop. Since I need to iterate through elements I guess..

Answer (score 1):

First of all your event listener shouldn't be inside that `forEach` block. What you are doing is that for every product (15) you add an event listener, so basically you're creating 15 event listeners. Also you're deleting the content with this statement: `containerProducts.innerHTML = "";`

If I understand correctly you want to click on the button and then loop through your products array and if they have certain id, you want to add them to a div :

- Place the event listener outside the `displayProducts` function.
- Pass the `displayProducts` as a callback to your event listener
- After you created your `html` variable, you can add your validation to run `containerProducts.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html);`

you should have something like this:

```js
cheeseHolder.addEventListener('click', displayProducts);

function displayProducts(event) {
  // you can do the products.forEach here
  // and inside the foreach you add your validation
  // to append the html to the containerProducts
}
```

I think this should help you

---

Edit March 22, 2021

So after clarifying the requirements I would recommend you doing the following

```
// have a function to render the elements
function displayProducts() {
}

// have another function to filter the items
function filterProducts(categoryId) {
   // loop your products array and add a condition 
   // to only display the ones which id matches the categoryId param
}

// for every filter button bind a click event

button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  filterProducts(1)
})

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  filterProducts(2)
})

// dont forget to call the displayProducts function 
// so all the items are visible in the screen
displayProducts()
```

I hope this is clear

Comment: What this does, is it displays the whole product list, where should the filtering actually go? I mean he if else statements

Comment: Plus even if I do this the list is disappearing after 1 moment again..

Comment: Ok so you want to display all the items and when you click the button you want to only display the items with id === 3 ?

Comment: That's right! So actually when you press on a product category display the category and remove the other products! If id===1 then display the categories with id of 1!

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer just updated the response, hope it helps